# Use of highcharts' addChart function within a getJSON call (looping over multiple local files)

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, highcharts, getjson

I'm really stuck here trying to get my head around highcharts combined with getjson and javascript loops (this is a follow on from a previous question - [How to generate highcharts chart from multiple local json files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603104/how-to-generate-highcharts-chart-from-multiple-local-json-files)).

Essentially I'm trying to create a highcharts barchart that contains multiple categories and series. I have a number of local json files that each contain counts of different information. I want to loop through each category file, read the count and add the result to that particular series (and then plot it). I'm using $.getJSON inside the loop that loops over the files (I think I now have that working by wrapping it in a function (see code below)). However, I'm also trying to use highchart's 'chart.addSeries' to add each new series to the chart (i.e. seriescount in the code). The way I have it coded currently means that I need to return the seriescount back out of the getJSON call - I know this isn't correct and instead should do the further processing inside of the getJSON call. And that's the part where I'm stuck - I'm not sure how I can handle adding new series inside the getJSON call as part of an evolving addition of multiple series.

I hope the above makes sense and if not maybe the code itself will help.

(Just to add that the majority of the code seems to work as expected - it's the final piece that I can't figure out)

Thanks for any advice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var options = {
  // standard highcharts options set here....
         series: []
  };

  //the series to loop through              
  var fileTypes = new Array('SeriesTypeA', 
                    'SeriesTypeB');

  //the categories to loop through                                      
  var mfiles = new Array('/assets/Cat1.json',
                 '/assets/Cat2.json',
                 '/assets/Cat3.json',
                 '/assets/Cat4.json',
                 '/assets/Cat5.json',
                 '/assets/Cat6.json',
                 '/assets/Cat7.json');

  //plot the initial empty chart              
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


  //Loop over the different files and do a count for each
  for (var i=0; i<fileTypes.length; i++) {  
      var seriescount = [];
      for (var j=0; j < mfiles.length; j++) {

          (function(i, j, seriescount){   //force the local i and j
              $.getJSON(mfiles[j], function(data) {
                  // get the count of files
                  var count = 0;
                  var index = 0;
                  var entry;
                  for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
                      entry = data[index];
                      if (entry.file_processing_status == fileTypes[i]) {
                          count ++;
                      }
                  };
                  seriescount.push(count);
                  return seriescount; //This is not correct
              }); 

          })(i, j, seriescount);
      }

      //add the results to make a new series               
      chart.addSeries({                        
          name: fileTypes[i],
          data: seriescount   //as expected I don't get seriescount at this stage
      }, false);            
  };

  //and now redraw the final chart          
  chart.redraw();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is disturbing, that's this line: `$.getJSON(mfiles[j], function(data) {` - that will mean you are loading for each series (`for` with `i` variable) the same file. For me that is strange.

Now about solution, each series has fixed number of categories, right? It's in `mfiles.length` variable. You can increase some counter, and add this (inside your getJSON callback):

```
if(categoryCounter == mfiles.length){ 
  chart.addSeries(series);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel, that's what I needed. With that counter added it's now working the way I wanted. I will work on cleaning up the code in reference to your first comments.